# Linux generic IRQ handling

Tags: linux-device-driver, interrupt, interrupt-handling

**Register an *linux generic interrupt handler* using an virtual irq which maps to the actual hwirq of domain to handle interrupts.**

I'm having issues in handling interrupts. So far I have registered an interrupt handler based on the following kernel docuentation [IRQ-domain.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/IRQ-domain.txt), by setting the ops and creating mapping between domain and hwirq. But unable to receive interrupts on the newly registered virtual interrupt line.

So my question's are:

1. Am I doing something wrong in the mapping because I am not seeing any interrupts getting handled in cat /proc/interrupts.
2. Should the request_thereaded_irq() consist of the actual hwirq and later handled in the threaded handler on virq as done in arizona.

Code Ref: [arizona-irq.c](https://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/mfd/arizona-irq.c)

```
static struct irq_chip irq_chip = {
    .name                   = "CHIP-IRQ",
    .irq_disable            = noop,
    .irq_enable             = noop,
};


static int irq_map(struct irq_domain *h, unsigned int virq,
                             irq_hw_number_t hw)
{
       struct chipdata *data = h->host_data;

       irq_set_chip_and_handler(virq, &irq_chip, handle_simple_irq);
       irq_set_chip_data(virq, data);
       irq_set_noprobe(virq);

       return 0;
}

static const struct irq_domain_ops irq_domain_ops = {
       .map    = irq_map,
       .xlate  = irq_domain_xlate_twocell,
};

/* Register an interrupt domain */    `
chipdata.irq_domain = irq_domain_create_linear( fwn, 20, &irq_domain_ops, ebus);
if (!chipdata.irq_domain) {
         dev_err(ebus->bus.dev, "Failed to add core IRQ domain\n");
}

/* Create mapping between domain and hwirq*/    
virq = irq_create_mapping( chipdata.irq_domain, hwirq);

ret = request_threaded_irq( virq, interrupt, threaded_interrupt, IRQF_SHARED, KBUILD_MODNAME, ebus);
if (ret) {
         dev_err(bus->dev, "unable to grab IRQ %d, disabling device\n", virq);
         return ret;
}
```

Comment: What the **exact** problem you are trying to solve? (Not the particular one with this twisted code, of course)

Comment: @0andriy I am trying to generalize interrupt handling in multiple audio codecs, the query I had was after creating mapping should I request handler first on hwirq and then on virq, or **does the mapping does it and directly place the handler onto virq**.. ref:arizona-irq.c

Comment: @0andriy They are using a nested implementation of interrupt handling, I tried skipping nested handlers and registered a single handler on virtual IRQ line and yeah!! interrupts doesn't appear.